# How to call aws lambda function from another lambda function in PHP?

Tags: php, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-serverless

I have  two lambda functions on AWS, which had created using lumen framework and bref package. Each functions have some API routes.

For example:

> Lambda function 1 (Books)
>
> 1. GET: books
> 2. GET: books/{id}
>
> Lambda function 2 (Authors)
>
> 1. GET: authors
> 2. GET: authors/{id}

How I can call `authors/{id}` API of authors lambda function from books lambda function, using AWS SDK for PHP?

Comment: You want to tightly couple your api calls? Why don't you 1. Call your book function. 2. Using your results from book function call authors function.

Comment: @FirebladeDan, thanks for your comment, but the idea behind its to implement the communication between lambda functions